# ASP.NET Select XML nodes based on attribute value in child element

Tags: asp.net, xml, xpath, selectnodes

I'm trying to loop through the XML below and find all `entry` elements where the underlying `category` element has the value `collection` for thr `term` attribute. There are 2 in the example below. And then for those get the value of the `href` attribute on the `link` element.
However, I can't seem to find the right selectors:

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <title>demo</title>
    <id>urn:uuid:071d9650-ae6c-11e7-8f1a-0800200c9a66</id>
    <link rel="self" href="https://test.com/atom/index.xml"/>
    <updated>2017-10-11T14:37:33+02:00</updated>
    <author>
        <name>Test</name>
        <uri>http://www.test.com</uri>
    </author>
    <generator version="1.8">Agent</generator>
    <entry>
        <title>YDEMO</title>
        <id>urn:uuid:15f44340-ae6c-11e7-8f1a-0800200c9a66</id>
        <category term="collection"/>
        <published>2017-10-11T13:41:53+02:00</published>
        <updated>2017-10-11T14:37:33+02:00</updated>
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://www.myurl.com" type="text/xml"/>
        <mcp:projectScenario xmlns:mcp="http://webservice.yes-co.nl/3mcp/1.5/atom-extension">NBvh</mcp:projectScenario>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <title>DEMO 2</title>
        <id>urn:uuid:25f44340-ae6c-11e7-8f1a-0800200c9a00</id>
        <category term="collection"/>
        <published>2017-10-11T13:42:53+02:00</published>
        <updated>2017-10-11T14:38:33+02:00</updated>
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://www.myurl2.com" type="text/xml"/>
        <mcp:projectScenario xmlns:mcp="http://webservice.yes-co.nl/3mcp/1.5/atom-extension">BBvh</mcp:projectScenario>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <title>photo</title>
        <id>12</id>
        <category term="metadata"/>
        <updated>2016-10-11T14:38:33+02:00</updated>
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://www.myurl2.com" type="text/xml"/>
    </entry>
    <entry
        xmlns:mcp="http://webservice.yes-co.nl/3mcp/1.5/atom-extension">
        <title>No title</title>
        <id>urn:uuid:6d65c57f-621f-4c15-8a1d-5dc967423d5d</id>
        <category term="media"/>
        <published>2017-10-11T13:39:43+02:00</published>
        <updated>2017-10-11T13:39:43+02:00</updated>
        <link
            xmlns:mcp="http://webservice.yes-co.nl/3mcp/1.5/atom-extension" rel="related" href="https://webservice.yes-co.com/3mcp/1.5/15f44340-ae6c-11e7-8f1a-0800200c9a66/media/6d65c57f-621f-4c15-8a1d-5dc967423d5d-large.jpg" type="image/jpg" mcp:mediaFormat="large"/>
    </entry>        
</feed>
```

Here's my code so far, but even though the `data` variable contains the above XML, the `nodeList.Count` line returns 0 results:

```
    Dim WC As New WebClient
    Dim data As String = WC.DownloadString("http://localhost/index.xml")

    Dim indexXML As New XmlDocument
    indexXML.LoadXml(data)

    Dim mgr As XmlNamespaceManager = New XmlNamespaceManager(indexXML.NameTable)
    mgr.AddNamespace("http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom", indexXML.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI)

    Dim node As XmlNode

    Dim root As XmlNode = indexXML.DocumentElement
    Dim nodeList As XmlNodeList = root.SelectNodes("/feed/entry")

    'now loop through all elements  with "category term=collection" in index.xml
    For i As Integer = 0 To nodeList.Count - 1
        If nodeList(i).SelectSingleNode("/category/@term=collection") IsNot Nothing Then
            LogMessage(nodeList(i).SelectSingleNode("/category/link/@href").Value)
        End If
    Next i
```

**UPDATE 1**
I want to select all 'entry' elements where it has a category node with `term=collection`. That part works through this statement: `indexXML.SelectNodes("/atom:feed/atom:entry[atom:category/@term=""collection""]", mgr)`

I want to start from the entry node and then I want to select the href attribute of subelement link of entry (and in the future other child elements of `entry`.
However, none of the examples I tried below, return the value of the `href` attribute. How can I fix that?

I now have this:

```
Dim mgr As XmlNamespaceManager = New XmlNamespaceManager(indexXML.NameTable)
mgr.AddNamespace("atom", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")

Dim root As XmlNode = indexXML.DocumentElement
Dim nodeList As XmlNodeList = indexXML.SelectNodes("/atom:feed/atom:entry[atom:category/@term=""collection""]", mgr)

'now loop through all collections in index.xml

For i As Integer = 0 To nodeList.Count - 1 '1 result found

'NONE OF CALLS BELOW RETURN THE VALUE OF HREF ATTRIBUTE
    If nodeList(i).SelectSingleNode("atom:/link/@href", mgr) IsNot Nothing Then
        LogMessage(nodeList(i).SelectSingleNode("atom:/link/@href", mgr).Value)
'error: 'atom:/link/@href' has an invalid qualified name.
    End If
Next i
```

**UPDATE 2**
Thanks to @Pawel I was able to select all `entry` nodes that have `project` as value for the `term` attribute on `category` node like so:

```
objectsXML.SelectNodes("/atom:feed/atom:entry[atom:category/@term=""project""]", mgr)
```

However, how can I add an additional criterium to this selector to filter out `entry` nodes that have value `NBvh` OR `BBvh` for node `mcp:projectScenario`?

**UPDATE 3**
I added an additional namespace to the manager:

```
mgr.AddNamespace("atom", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")
mgr.AddNamespace("mcp", "http://webservice.yes-co.nl/3mcp/1.5/atom-extension")
```

But when I try to select the `href` attribute of the media element by uuid, I get the error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

My code:

```
objectsXML.SelectSingleNode("/atom:feed/atom:entry[atom:id=""urn:uuid:" + "6d65c57f-621f-4c15-8a1d-5dc967423d5d" + """]/mcp:link/@href", mgr).InnerText
```

Comment: Have no idea how code in `asp` should look like, but `/feed/entry[category/@term="collection"]/link/@href` should return you list of required nodes

Comment: Hi, unfortunately still 0 results with that selector. Btw: the reason that I wanted to select the `entry` node, is that I can then easily select other childnodes (like `link`, but there are more)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document uses the `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom` namespace. You need to bind this namespace to a uri prefix and use this prefix in your XPath.
If you bind the namespace to the `atom` prefix like this:

```
var nsmanager = new XmlNamespaceManager(indexXML.NameTable);
nsmanager.AddNamespace("atom", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
```

You will be able to use this prefix in your XPath expressions if you pass the namespace manager e.g.:

```
indexXML.SelectNodes("/atom:feed/atom:entry[atom:category/@term="collection"]/atom:link/@href", nsmanager)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way where I don't have to add that `atom` prefix to all my XSL expressions and also pass the namespacemanager? To be honest I think it makes things overly complex. I can imagine setting this up initially, but after that I would want to use regular non-prefixed XSL expressions...is that possible? I tried `mgr.AddNamespace("", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")` and then `Dim nodeList As XmlNodeList = root.SelectNodes("/feed/entry")` but that still return 0 results.

Comment: There are a few options but I am not sure if they are better. You can use local names e.g. `/*[local-name() = 'feed']`. You can traverse the tree manually checking the LocalNode property. You can use Linq to Xml where you can use namespace Uri directly. You can't use an empty string for namespace prefix. btw. in places where you look for `category` in your code you are using absolute node path (i.e. starting from `/` but it should be relative to the  current node)

Comment: Thanks. I added update 1, and for now am ok with the prefix. Right now I can select the `entry` element, but I want to select the `entry` element and THEN select its child elements (in this case the `link` element with ) based on another selector. Can you help?

Comment: As I said, you can't put `/` in front of every XPath expression - because you start at the document element. For instance you have `/atom:link/@href` but  the `atom:link` element is not the root node so cannot be found. If you want to make the expression relative to the context node you need to have `atom:link/@href. Other expression don't work because you are missing namespace prefixes.

Comment: Ah, missed that. I changed the selector and now it's indeed found. However to get the value, both the property `.Value` and `.InnerText` throw the error `'atom:/link/@href' has an invalid qualified name.`...why?

Comment: because it is not `atom:/link` but `atom:link`

Comment: thanks. I'm now running into a followup issue on the existing selector. See update 2 in my post. How could I add this criterium? Do I need to do this in 2 separate selections, or can it be done in 1 single selection (even though it has a different namespace)? Thank you again!

Comment: @Flo Answer to your followup: `objectsXML.SelectNodes("/atom:feed/atom:entry[atom:category/@term='project' and not (mcp:projectScenario[. = 'NVBh' or . = 'BBVH'])]", mgr)`

Comment: Thank you @JLRishe. That code throws error: `'/atom:feed/atom:entry[atom:category/‌​@term='project' and not (mcp:projectScenario[. = 'NVBh' or . = 'BBVH'])]' has an invalid token.`
Also I DO want to ONLY include values 'NBvh' and 'BBvh', so I corrected the values to be checked and removed the `not` operator from your example. Resulting in `objectsXML.SelectNodes("/atom:feed/atom:entry[atom:category/‌​@term=""project"" and (mcp:projectScenario[. = ""NBvh"" or . = ""BBvh""])]", mgr)` But still I get the same error. How can I correct it?

Comment: @Flo Not sure how, but somehow a unicode zero-width space and a zero-width non-joiner slipped in between `category/`and `@term`, maybe when you copy/pasted the XPath. This is valid and should work (I've removed the invalid invisible characters): `/atom:feed/atom:entry[atom:category/@term='project' and mcp:projectScenario[. = 'NBvh' or . = 'BBvh']]`

Comment: @JLRishe weird, never seen that happen before. Now I get another error though: `Namespace prefix 'mcp' is not defined.`

Comment: @Flo You need to add the `mcp` prefix to the namespace manager, same as you're doing with the `atom` prefix.

Comment: @JLRishe Thanks! I did not know I could add multiple namespaces to a single namespace manager! I did that now, but still get an error, see update 3.

Comment: @Flo The path in update 3 should have atom:link, not mcp:link. You're getting an error because the path is failing to select anything and SelectSingleNode is returning `Nothing`.